# Smooth transitions between page loads

Tags: javascript, css, events, css-transitions

I built a JavaScript plugin that will rotate between various pages. Before going to the next page, the opacity is changed over 1/2 second.  This part seems to work as desired.

```
function redirectPage(nextpage) {
    document.body.style.opacity = 0;
    document.body.style.transition = '500ms opacity';
    setTimeout(function (){
        window.location.href = nextpage;
        }, 500);
}
```

When the next page is displayed, the intent is to continue with the zero opacity of the previous page and transition to full opacity over the next 1/2 second.  I've tried three possible solutions with limited success.

1. Use `document.body.style` to change the `body` opacity to zero.  The plugin's JavaScript is located in the `head` and thus executed before the `body` is downloaded, and then additional JavaScript is located a the end of the `body` which allows `enableRotator` to be applied after the DOM is loaded.  Originally, I wasn't using the `DOMContentLoaded` callback, but experienced errors as there was no `body` to apply style to.  Even after adding it however, is not working as desired.  It appears that the page is first displayed in full opacity, then flickers to zero opacity, and then transitions to full opacity over 1/2 second.  Anyone know why?
2. Use `document.write` to write some css.  Initial attempts resulted in `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at window.onload`.  Anyone know why?  I've since found moving it outside of the `DOMContentLoaded` callback eliminates the error, but still have the same shortcoming as encounter in my third attempt.
3. Instead of writing style, create the style in the DOM.  Both this solution and the previous #2 solution do not experience solution #1's flicker, but do not transition in the page but instantly show it.

How can I implement a fade-in and fade-out between pages?

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    //document.write("<style>body {opacity 0;}</style>");
    //var style = document.createElement('style');
    //style.type = 'text/css';
    //style.innerHTML = 'body {opacity 0;}';
    //document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
    document.body.style.opacity = 0;
    document.body.style.transition = 'none';
    window.onload=function(){
        document.body.style.opacity = 1;
        document.body.style.transition = '500ms opacity';
    };
});

function enableRotator(){
    //plugin goes here....
}
```

Comment: Can't you just set it in CSS? `body { opacity: 0; }`, and then fade the body in on document-ready?

Comment: @rblarsen  Yes I could, but my hopes were to utilize a single JS file.